# HDR rendering on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0, hdr

I'm targeting OpenGL ES 3.0, which guarantees support for floating point textures but requires `OES_color_buffer_half_float` or `OES_color_buffer_float` for actually rendering to them.

I'm itching to code and test HDR rendering on Android. Are there any Android devices on or entering the market in the next few months, supporting the `OES_color_buffer_half_float` extension? Alternatively, is there any way to implement HDR as a post-processing effect without rendering to a floating point texture?

Comment: nVidia Shield Tablet supports `GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float` extension which may be what you need. You can check out extensions of some other newest devices at http://gfxbench.com/result.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a database with OpenGL (ES) capabilities online.
For your color buffer half float extension, see this page:

[glcapsviewer](http://delphigl.de/glcapsviewer/gles_listreports.php?extension=GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float)

Many devices are listed as having this extension.